# Change in Python earthengine API? filePerBand being ignored by makeDownloadUrl?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

This code used to work on RGB data (MODIS, Sentinel2, etc) and would give me a single TIFF file:

```
image = clipped_data.visualize(['sur_refl_b02', 'sur_refl_b02', 'sur_refl_b01'], gain=0.03, gamma=1)

url = ee.data.makeDownloadUrl(ee.data.getDownloadId({
    'image': image,
    'scale': 400,
    'filePerBand': 'false',
    'name': 'data'
    }))
print(url)
local_zip, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
```

Running the code now and the behaviour has changed and what used to be a single data.tiff file is now 3 files, 'data.vis-red.tif', 'data.vis-green.tif', 'data.vis-blue.tif'.

My code hasn't changed at all so I can't work out what's going on. `filePerBand` seems to be being ignored now?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The documentation has this at the top in bold italics: *Important Note: Access to Google Earth Engine is currently only available to registered users. The API is in active development, and users should expect the API to change. When (not if) API changes occur, applications that use the API will likely need to be updated.* This seems like a bug that should be reported through appropriate channels.

Comment: I'm aware the API can change but I can't find any reference to them removing the filePerBand from the API. What I'm asking is if anyone can spot why the above is now wrong or whether it is indeed a bug.